# How to copy Images from one path to new path in Amazon S3 (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

We use Amazon S3 to save picture for our project but now we need to copy some images from one place to another in S3. I have older/saved images path stored in my DB and now wants to save them using new path.

Can someone please guide me in any right direction to start with. I have been looking into `CopyObjectRequest` but can't figure out how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic example with `original` and `destination` variables being passed to the function from the caller.

```
public void DuplicateFileInCloud(string original, string destination)
{
    try
    {
        CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest();

        if (original.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            // example: http://jk-v30.s3.amazonaws.com/PredefinedFiles/Favicons/002.ico
            string bucket = getBucketNameFromUrl(original), // i.e. jk-v30
                    key = getKeyFromUrl(original);          // the path to your file: PredefinedFiles/Favicons/002.ico

            request.WithSourceBucket(bucket);
            request.WithSourceKey(key);
        }
        else
        {
            // same bucket: copy/paste operation
            request.WithSourceBucket(this.bucketName);
            request.WithSourceKey(original);
        }

        request.WithDestinationBucket(this.bucketName);
        request.WithDestinationKey(destination);
        request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead; // one way of setting public headers - see other below

        using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(this.accessKey, this.secretAccessKey))
        {
            S3Response response = client.CopyObject(request);
            response.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
    {
        throw s3Exception;
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

**Setting `public-read`**

```
response.Addheader("x-amz-acl","public-read");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm adaam, Thanks

Comment: One thing i would like to add if anyone stumbles here is parameter ````original```` should not include bucket.com address. ex original in above case will be ````PredefinedFiles/Favicons/002.ico````